# Can we add a new node in riak kv test environment?

Tags: riak

There are 5 nodes (dev/dev1....dev/dev5) configured in test environment. Can we add a new node dev/dev6 to the cluster? If we can add it, will it replicate data after joining the node to the cluster?

Riak version is 1.4.7. I am planning to update riak to latest version as the current test version is way too old. But before that I need to check if we can add a new node to the above setup I mentioned.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just realized that you might be referring to the Riak test application https://github.com/basho/riak_test. It is not clear from your question. A Riak KV test environment can be just a regular setup.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear and late in replying to your comment, 
I was asking if we can add a remote node to the existing single node cluster which has 5(dev1..dev5) nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to resurrect an old question but, as it is still a valid question, the answer is yes.

Complete the following steps and it should work fine:

- Configure dev6 so that it has the same riak-cookie and ring size as the nodes in the existing cluster (look in *riak.conf* or *app.config* for these settings) and can also access the other nodes via the network.
- Start dev6 via `riak start`.
- Tell it to join the cluster with `riak-admin join [node name of node already in cluster]` (remove the square brackets and substitute a node name in accordingly of a node already in the cluster e.g. `riak-admin join dev3@192.168.0.3`).
- Plan the cluster transition with `riak-admin cluster plan`.
- Check the generated plan and, if happy, commit with `riak-admin cluster commit`.
- Wait for transfers to finish (you can monitor them with `riak-admin transfers`.

Your node should now be part of the cluster and working fine.

NB: If your Riak KV version is Riak KV 3.0.0 or higher, please substitute `riak admin` instead of `riak-admin` for all occurrences above.

In the event that you want to create an additional dev node on your test box:

- Copy all the folders and files from an existing dev node except the data directory to a new folder.
- Go through *riak.conf* and *advanced.config* (or *vm.args* and *app.config* on version 1.x of Riak) and substitute out all the clashing ports for ones that will not clash with other dev nodes in the test cluster.
- Create an empty data directory for the new node and the node should be good to start.

NB: Default devrel creation on KV 1.x was 5 nodes whereas from KV 2.x and higher, it is 8 nodes. None of these nodes are configured inside a cluster at creation. You can also change this to a higher or lower number of nodes when you build them e.g. `make devrel DEVNODES=10 locked-deps` will give you 10 dev nodes automatically configured with non-clashing ports but you need to make sure you have the resources to actually run all 10!